# Implementing fields in Scala generic classes

Tags: scala, generics, types, abstract

I need some help with generic traits in Scala.

I have a class with a method that returns a type T.
In every implementation of my class, I want to return a sub-class of T which can be used.

Basically, in my abstract class I need a method returning a Configs object and every implementation will have it's own implementation of a Configs object.
In addition, I want to subclass the abstract class with another abstract class, restricting this Configs object even more (a sub-class of the original Configs object). No matter what I do, I get compile errors.

This is what I've tried:

```
case class MyConfigs()

trait WithMyConfigs {
  def myConfigs: MyConfigs
}

case class LimitConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, limit: Int) extends WithMyConfigs

case class TextConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, text: String) extends WithMyConfigs


    trait AbstractClass {
      def configs[B <: WithMyConfigs]: B
    }

    class ImplLimitClass extends AbstractClass {
      override def configs[B <: WithMyConfigs]: B = LimitConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
    }

    class ImplSizeClass extends AbstractClass {
      override def configs[B <: WithMyConfigs]: B = TextConfigs(MyConfigs(), "test")
    }

    trait WithRestrictedConfigs extends WithMyConfigs {
      def additionalIntField: Int
    }

    trait RestrictedAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
      override def configs[B <: WithRestrictedConfigs]: B
    }

    case class RestrictedConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, additionalIntField: Int) extends WithRestrictedConfigs

    class ImplRestrictedClass extends RestrictedAbstractClass {
      override def configs[B <: WithRestrictedConfigs]: B = RestrictedConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
    }
```

With this I get the errors 'Expression of type TextConfigs/LimitConfigs doesn't conform to expected type B'.

I've also tried the following:

```
case class MyConfigs()

trait WithMyConfigs {
  def myConfigs: MyConfigs
}

case class LimitConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, limit: Int) extends WithMyConfigs

case class TextConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, text: String) extends WithMyConfigs


trait AbstractClass {

  type B <: WithMyConfigs

  def configs: B
}

class ImplLimitClass extends AbstractClass {
  override def configs: B = LimitConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}

class ImplSizeClass extends AbstractClass {
  override def configs: B = TextConfigs(MyConfigs(), "test")
}

trait WithRestrictedConfigs extends WithMyConfigs {
  def additionalIntField: Int
}

trait RestrictedAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
  override type B <: WithRestrictedConfigs
  override def configs: B
}

case class RestrictedConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, additionalIntField: Int) extends WithRestrictedConfigs

class ImplRestrictedClass extends RestrictedAbstractClass {
  override def configs: B = RestrictedConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}
```

And then I get 'Expression of type XXX doesn't conform to expected type ImplRestrictedClass.this.B'.

If anyone knows how to help, that'd be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the actual types in your implementations. Have a look at the [scala-doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-types.html).

Here is an example that compiles:

```
case class MyConfigs()

trait WithMyConfigs {
  def myConfigs: MyConfigs
}

case class LimitConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, limit: Int) extends WithMyConfigs

case class TextConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, text: String) extends WithMyConfigs


trait AbstractClass {
  type T <: WithMyConfigs
  def configs :T
}

class ImplLimitClass extends AbstractClass {
  type T = LimitConfigs
  override def configs: T = LimitConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}

class ImplSizeClass extends AbstractClass {
  type T = TextConfigs
  override def configs: T = TextConfigs(MyConfigs(), "test")
}

trait WithRestrictedConfigs extends WithMyConfigs {
  def additionalIntField: Int
}

trait RestrictedAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
  type T <: WithRestrictedConfigs
  override def configs: T
}

case class RestrictedConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, additionalIntField: Int) extends WithRestrictedConfigs

class ImplRestrictedClass extends RestrictedAbstractClass {
  type T = RestrictedConfigs
  override def configs: T = RestrictedConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}
```

[UPDATE]

You will need to specify your type somewhere. If using type parameters you will get something like:

```
trait AbstractClass[T <: WithMyConfigs] {
  def configs: T
}

class ImplLimitClass extends AbstractClass[LimitConfigs] {
  override def configs = LimitConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}

class ImplSizeClass extends AbstractClass[WithMyConfigs] {
  override def configs = TextConfigs(MyConfigs(), "test")
}
```

Of course you can specify the trait itself to get a more general config (see `ImplSizeClass` above)
And then hide the type parameter with an extra trait.

```
trait SpecAbstractClass extends AbstractClass[WithMyConfigs]
```

If you don't want to specify explicit types anyway, why not use the old fashioned way of using interfaces:

```
case class MyConfigs()

trait WithMyConfigs {
  def myConfigs: MyConfigs
}

case class LimitConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, limit: Int) extends WithMyConfigs

case class TextConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, text: String) extends WithMyConfigs


trait AbstractClass {
  def configs: WithMyConfigs
}

class ImplLimitClass extends AbstractClass {
  override def configs = LimitConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}

class ImplSizeClass extends AbstractClass {
  override def configs = TextConfigs(MyConfigs(), "test")
}

trait WithRestrictedConfigs extends WithMyConfigs {
  def additionalIntField: Int
}

trait RestrictedAbstractClass extends AbstractClass {
  override def configs: WithRestrictedConfigs
}

case class RestrictedConfigs(myConfigs: MyConfigs, additionalIntField: Int) extends WithRestrictedConfigs

class ImplRestrictedClass extends RestrictedAbstractClass {
  override def configs = RestrictedConfigs(MyConfigs(), 5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Is there no way for me to implement those Config classes without having to define the type explicitly?